# Angular Filter by scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how is it possible to filer like this?

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: {city: '{{city}}' }"
```

All friends should get selected, who live in specific city, which is selected in a view before this view. The {{city}} is in scope. Works outside the ng-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
| filter: {city: city}
```

Don't use a string.  The scope value will be interpolated in `ng-repeat` just like `friends` is.

Answer (score 0):

please see here:http://jsbin.com/cihas/1/edit

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: {city: city}"></ion-item>
```